# How to access files uploaded to the public folder in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a project in Next.js. I have that upload files and share that in public URL to this project.

With `npm run dev` first I uploaded files to `public` folder and it worked fine, but when I change to `npm run start` and upload files, the files upload to `public` folder but with URL `http://mydomain/fileuploaded.jpg` it did not show, is rare but it's there.

I searched on the Internet but I didn't find a solution for this problem.

Comment: Ok, but is annoying, because all examples that i saw in internet was uploading files to `public folder` :/

Comment: I have the same problem, did you ever solve it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Next.js documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving):

> Only assets that are in the public directory at build time will be served by Next.js. Files added at runtime won't be available.

You'll have to persist the uploaded files somewhere else if you want to have access to them in the app at run time.

---

Alternatively, you could setup your own [custom server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) in Next.js, which would give you more control to [serve static files/assets](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/12656#issuecomment-641025110).

You can also achieve something similar using API routes instead. See [Next.js serving static files that are not included in the build or source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70490959/next-js-serving-static-files-that-are-not-included-in-the-build-or-source-code) for details.

Answer (score 2):

Try and use nginx or another webserver to serve the public directory. That way it will serve newly added files without having to write extra code to serve files in nextjs.

```
server {
  /images/ {
    root /var/www/site/public
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

a bit late but if someone need the same.

If your goal is to upload and get picture from your next server, you can instead of using the Next router, getting the image by yourself by create a route `/api/images/[id]` where [id] is your file name and you manually with `fs` send the picture back.

something like:

```
const file = await fs.readFile(`./uploads/image.png`)

res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png')
res.send(file)
```

Comment: Just make sure you adequately sanitize IDs so a malicious user doesn't access secure files using a crafted URL like `/api/images/../../some-secret-file-on-the-server.json`