# EACCES :Permission denied open 'image/url... ' : when trying to upload image in nextjs

Tags: next.js

[image]

**image upload is working fine on localhost but its not working on deployment**

Comment: The error is pretty obvious. You should give sufficient permissions to the folder which you are trying to upload.

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, but keep in mind that files added to the `public` folder at runtime won't be available to be served: [How to access files uploaded to the public folder in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68289723/1870780).