# How to access public directory images when the app is in .next folder in nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

After building my next application by running `npm run build`, all the images in the public folder are being stored as static images which I believe is how it is expected to work. However, I want to access the images in the public directory from the .next folder as I am adding new images to it every time.

Here is
[the folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hq06.png)

If it requires any change to happen in the folder structure like moving the public folder to any other location or making a new directory, it would still be fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to access files uploaded to the public folder in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68289723/1870780)?

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! Had this problem with this for 2 days now. Was gonna cry if it had not been resolved.