# Next.js Dynamically added Images + Client side referenced

Tags: reactjs, image, dynamic, next.js, filepath

in /public/ I have a folder called /public/cms_images.

cms_images gets populated whenever a user uploads an image using the admin portal we created (seperate from the next.js project, its asp.net and just throws images into my next.js project's folder)

On the /pageThatUsesImage.js the page works and references the image if I build the application and serve it (next build && next start)

**But when a new image gets added, the image throws a 404**

I reference the filename + filetype for the image via a client side api call.

```js
                 <img
                      src={`/cms_images/` + dataFromPageAPI.imageFileName}
                    />
```

Is there any work around to getting dynamically added images to show on run time?

Comment: can you console.log `dataFromPageAPI.imageFileName`

Comment: Yep. @ChemiAdel

"image_546.jpg"

Comment: @try this `/cms_images/${dataFromPageAPI.imageFileName}`

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to access files uploaded to the public folder in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68289723/1870780)? You can't access files added at runtime to the `public` folder.

Comment: @juliomalves I know that - I'm just trying to find a solution for dynamically added images post-build.

Comment: That answer has some suggestions.

Comment: Did you find a solution without using s3?