Using express.static as a Route Handler in Nextjs App Router
I have a Nextjs app that needs to serve files from folders other than /public.
I have done this before, using Page router, with an approach similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70490960.
However now I'm using App router, and the same approach doesn't work. I expected this to work:
// src/app/api/external/[filename]/route.ts

import express from 'express'

// TODO: remove hardcoded path
const externalDir =
  '/path/to/externa/directory'

const handler = express();


handler.use(
  '/api/external',
  express.static(
    externalDir
  ));

export const GET = handler

But I get TypeError: Cannot set property url of #<NextRequest> which has only a getter.
I thought this would be a fairly standard use case, so I'm surprised it doesn't work and I can see no other approach promoted.
