# How use Certbot with NEXTJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, certbot

I use certbot with following command:

`sudo certbot certonly -a webroot --webroot-path=/dirrectory/public -d example.com`

The problem is that **Certbot** use public folder for create the challenge and **NEXTJS** disable all changes in folder `/public` when is in poduction (`npm start`). So what is the best way to create a certbot SSL with NEXTJS?

I used a [nextjs custom server](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/12656#issuecomment-641025110) , but It did not work

Thanks coders and happy new year

Comment: _"NEXTJS disable all changes in folder `/public`"_ - Can you clarify this statement? At what point are you running the `certbot` command? Next.js will serve anything that's in the `public` folder at build time.

Comment: When you run `npm start` in NEXT  and later you desire add a file `img.jpg` to folder public, you can add the file, but this file will not find when you search in your  project's url:

`http://example.com/img.jpg`

Comment: That's expected, files added at runtime won't be served by Next.js. See [How to access files uploaded to the public folder in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68289723/1870780).