# I can't read a pdf in production mode Next

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I have a problem in my next js project when I do the "yarn build" and then "yarn start" and I try to read a pdf that was before doing the "build" and the "start" if I can see it in my browser by putting the path where I put it but if I already did the "build" and "start" and I add a pdf file manually to my next project in this case to the public folder and I try to access it from my browser by putting the path where I am sure it is it sent me a 404 error

I hope you can help me

[image]

If I can access the sample.pdf but the other pdf I can access

[image]

I hope you can help me thank you very much

Comment: Only assets that are in the `public` folder at build time will be served by Next.js. See [How to access files uploaded to the public folder in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68225815/how-to-access-files-uploaded-to-the-public-folder-in-next-js).

Answer (score 0):

When you run `yarn build`/`npm run build`/`pnpm run build`, NextJS copies everything from your `public` folder and puts it in the `.next` folder along with the transpiled javascript. If you want to add something to the public folder after you build it, you need to put it where the other pdfs are in the `.next` folder (probably in some subdirectory)

Comment: I could not find them but for example if I delete the sample.pdf file I can no longer access it with the browser and if I restore it I can access it again, because the same does not happen with the other file that I added after doing the "yarn build" :(