# how to access files in public folder from url in next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm on a next js project which users are allowed to upload images, I store image in my public directory, is there any way I can access my file with a url structure like mydomain.com/public/coverimg/image.jpg

this is my api code below.

```
 import { rejects } from 'assert';
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { promises } from 'stream';

const fs = require('fs');
const moment = require('moment');
const formidable = require('formidable-serverless');
var slugify = require('slugify');
const path = require('path');
const crypto = require('crypto');

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

const handler = async (req, res) => {
  const timeStamp = moment().format('DD_MM_YYYY');

  const Image_id = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');

  fs.mkdir(
    `./public/coverimg/${timeStamp}`,
    { recursive: true },
    function (err) {
      res.send(err);
    }
  );

  const data = await new Promise((resolve, rejects) => {
    const form = formidable({
      multple: false,
      uploadDir: `./public/coverimg/${timeStamp}`,
    });

    
    form.KeepExtentions = true;
    form.KeepFileName = true;
    form.maxFields = 1000;

    form.on('fileBegin', function (name, file) {
      file.path = path.join(
        `./public/coverimg/${timeStamp}`,
        Image_id + '_' + slugify(file.name)
      );
    });

    // console.log(data);
    form.parse(req, (error, fields, files) => {
      if (error) return rejects(error);
      resolve(files);
    });
  });
};

export default handler;
```

Comment: Well, by default you can access any file in the `public` folder by just navigating to it, like so for example, `domain.com/filename.jpg` and if you have nested directories, then you can access them in the same way as well. Unless you want to upload and access in runtime, in this case, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68225815/how-to-access-files-uploaded-to-the-public-folder-in-next-js)

Answer (score 2):

You should share the URL in the next format:

```
{YOUR_DOMAIN}/{IMAGE_NAME}.{FORMAT}
```

For example

```
https://my.app.domain/1676292852306cle2thet7000iv73y7xk39o2d.png
```

Note: Do not include `/public/` in your shared url.